# How do you install Django 2x on pip when python 2x is your default version of python but you use python 3x on Bash

Tags: python, django, bash, macos, pip

I need to install Django 2.2.2 on my MacBook pro (latest generation), and I am a user of python 3x.  However, my default version of python is python 2x and I cannot pip install Django version 2x when I am using python 2x.  Could anyone explain how to change the default version of python on MacBook I have looked at many other questions on this site and none have worked.  All help is appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `pip3` instead of `pip` to install Python 3 packages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have python2 and python3 in your laptop but python2 is default and you want to install django 2.2.2 which is the latest version.
First always use a virtual environment.
Do the following on your terminal:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Then:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

After that, then use pip like below:

```
pip install django
```

The latest django will be installed on that environment

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, It worked and I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there any way that I can change the default version of python anyway?

Comment: Accept this answer if it worked. [Here's how you can change the default python.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.maketecheasier.com/using-python-3-on-mac/%3famp)